# How can we avoid gac installed third party components?

Tags: visual-studio, registry

We are developing software which uses third party components with build and runtime licencing (if the software is not installed on the developer machine, visual studio complains when trying to generate a licence). Are there any general ways to register the required information in the registry without installing the third party components? The reason for asking is because the difference between a developer machine and the typical client/tester machine is the biggest reason for the "works on my machine"-syndrome. We want to emulate the client enviroment, which means avoiding as many locally installed third party components as possible on the dev machines.

Comment: When the license verification becomes a support cost then it is time to get another license.  Give them a call, anything is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is a VM. Registry hacks won't magically create licenses.

Comment: You mean to use a virtual machine on the dev machines for testing?

Comment: Yes. It's trivial to make sure that you use the very same VM on every dev machine, for each test. That way you don't even have Visual Studio itself installed for the test.